# How can I find out my current gvfs version?

Tags: versions, gvfs

I would like to know the official version number of my gvfs install.

However none of the gvfs tools seems to offer a -v option.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Try `dpkg -l | grep 'gvfs' | awk '{print $2,$3}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the package installed on your system:

```
$ dpkg -p gvfs | grep Version
Version: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1
```

**Tip:** Better obtain package information, directly via `dpkg -p`.